# Flutter DateTime picker Scrollable error?

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter_datetime_picker package for selecting manual date. Here's the code:

```
DatePicker.showDatePicker(
 context,
 showTitleActions: true,
 minTime: DateTime.now(),
 maxTime: DateTime(2024, 12, 31),
 onConfirm: (date) async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('orders')
  .doc(order['orderId'])
  .update({
   'deliverystatus': 'shipping',
   'deliverydate': date.toString(),
  });
 },
);
```

As soon as I scroll
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7JNL.jpg), I receive the following error:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
FixedExtentScrollPhysics can only be used with Scrollables that uses the FixedExtentScrollController
'package:flutter/src/widgets/list_wheel_scroll_view.dart':
list_wheel_scroll_view.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 464 pos 7: 'position is _FixedExtentScrollPosition'
```

In the documentation for the said package, there's no mention for scrollables. Also if I try to use controller, how should I use it and to what 'extent' should I initialize it?

Package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_datetime_picker

I tried using controller but don't know how to initialize it's extent for 'month', 'year' and 'date'.

Comment: minTime is causing error i think. try to extend it little a bit then try again

Comment: working fine on web for me

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.